# check a large file .csv and replace, and classify it in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-mining

I need to check a large file .csv and replace, and classify it in one column `dataframe['value']`.

This is my code, but it works slowly:

```
def encoder():
    classes={}
    a=dataframe['value']
    c=-1
    for i in a:
        if i not in classes:
            print(i)
            c=c+1
            classes[i]=c
    for i in range(len(a)):
        print(i)
        dataframe['value'][i]=classes[a[i]]
```

Is there a better solution?

This is part of my dataset:

```
subject_id  hadm_id seq_num icd9_code   icustay_id  value   valueuom
18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    Tracheostomy    0
18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    Tracheostomy    0
18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    Tracheostomy    0
18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    Tracheostomy    0
18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    30  0
18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    30  0
18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    30  0
18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    30  0
18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    2 Person Assist 0
18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    2 Person Assist 0
18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    2 Person Assist 0
18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    2 Person Assist 0
18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    Calm    0
18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    Calm    0
18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    Calm    0
18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    Calm    0
18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    Present 0
18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    Present 0
18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    Present 0
18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    Present 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by classify it ?
If you want to extract all distinct values in a column, use df['column'].drop_duplicates()

Comment: From the looks of what your doing you can just create the dictionary for classes and apply a MAP.  Also, if you just want to set one value to the whole column, you can just do df['value'] = 0

Comment: Can you put some more details to your data, specially **value** column ? Does it also contain null values, or it is only 0 ? Does this column have skipped values or does not have consecutive values? Is that why you wanna reclassify it ?

Comment: Also, I would suggest you go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It would help you write fine, clean questions with necessary details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few assumptions I am making from your code, let me know if I am wrong.

1. The task is to encode the values of the column **value** in the dataframe.
2. I am assuming **value** column is not having any null values and has only numbers.
3. From your code, I am also assuming you are not allowed to use libraries like **sklearn** or anything to do this.

Under these assumptions, below code might help you.

```
x = sorted(dataframe["value"].unique())
y = list(range(0, len(x)))

encoded_dict = dict(zip(x, y))
dataframe["value"] = dataframe["value"].apply(lambda x: encoded_dict[x])
```

Comment: 1. Yes, the task is to encode values in column value. 2. No, column consist of different types(str, int, floats, etc) and null value. 3. I tried to use Ordinalencoder, but it raises an error.

Comment: Then in that case going for label encoder from sklearn will do the thing for you